# Taxonomy code not working

Tags: php, post, taxonomy

**ourteam.php**

```
<?php
    /*
     Template Name: OUR TEAM
    */
    get_header();
?>

<div class="container ourteamah">
    <h3>Our Team</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">

            <div class="tab-wrap1">
                <div class="media1">
                    <div class="parrent1 pull-left">
                          <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('our-team-sidebar') ) : endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="parrent1 media1-body">
                        <div class="tab-content">

                            <?php $arr = array('posts_per_page' => '11', 'taxonomy'=>'Doctor-Categories', 'order' => 'ASC', 'category_id' =>33);
                                $posts = get_posts($arr);

                                foreach($posts as $data){

                                    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($data ->ID) );

                                    $custom_subheading = get_post_custom($data->ID);
                                    $custom_subheading_key = $custom_subheading['team-sub-heading'];
                                    $custom_subheading_array = $custom_subheading_key[0];

                                    $custom_class_key = $custom_subheading['class'];
                                    $custom_class_array = $custom_class_key[0];

                                    $custom_id_key = $custom_subheading['id'];
                                    $custom_id_array = $custom_id_key[0];
                            ?>

                            <div class="<?php echo $custom_class_array;?>" id="<?php echo $custom_id_array;?>">
                                <div class="media1">
                                   <div class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumb;?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media1-body">
                                         <h4><?php echo $data->post_title;?></h4>
                                         <h2><?php echo $custom_subheading_array;?></h2>
                                         <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                                <?php echo $data->post_content;?> 
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php } ?>

                        </div> <!--/.tab-content-->  
                    </div> <!--/.media1-body--> 
                </div> <!--/.media1-->     
            </div><!--/.tab-wrap1-->               
        </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->

    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

**functions.php**

```
<?php

//Defining paths for css,js,file,plugins
define('AHL_URL',WP_CONTENT_URL."/");
define('AHL_IMG_URL',WP_CONTENT_URL."/themes/ahalia/images/");
define('AHL_STYLE_URL',WP_CONTENT_URL."/css/");
define('AHL_SCRIPT_URL',WP_CONTENT_URL."/js/");


/*fastsolution Theme and Functions goes in this file*/

//adding menus in dashboard
add_theme_support('menus');
//adding featured image
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 

//adding widgets
function ahalia_widgets_init() {

//adding php support to widget

function php_execute($html){
if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){ ob_start(); eval("?".">".$html);
 $html=ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
}
return $html;
}
 add_filter('widget_text','php_execute',100);


 //adding post-formats
 add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
 'aside', 'audio', 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status',      'video') );

 //addig search form
 add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form' ) );


 add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
  'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list', 'gallery', 'caption'
  ) );

 //callig search for and resuls dont delete this will run on 404 error page

 function SearchFilter($query) {
 // If 's' request variable is set but empty
 if (isset($_GET['s']) && empty($_GET['s']) && $query->is_main_query()){
 $query->is_search = true;
 $query->is_home = false;
 }
 return $query;
 }
 add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

 //nav menus
 register_nav_menus( array(
  'header_menu' => 'HEADER',
  'navigation' => 'FOOTER_NAVIG',
  'quick_links' => 'FOOTER_QUICK'
 ) );   

//custom post type strats for slider
function testimonial_postTypes(){
$labels = array(
'name'               => _x( 'Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
'singular_name'      => _x( 'Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
'add_new'            => _x( 'Add Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New testimonial' ),
'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Testimonial' ),
'new_item'           => __( 'New Testimonial' ),
'all_items'          => __( 'All Testimonial' ),
 'view_item'          => __( 'View Testimonial' ,'Testimonial'),
 'search_items'       => __( 'Search Testimonial' ),
 'not_found'          => __( 'No Testimonial found' ),
 'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Testimonial found in the Trash' ), 
 'parent_item_colon'  => '',
 'menu_name'          => 'Testimonial'
  );
 $args = array(
 'labels'                => $labels,
 'description'       => 'Allows the user to create Testimonial',
  'public'           => true,
  'menu_icon'        =>        '"'.WP_CONTENT_URL.'"/themes/ahalia/images/testimonial.png',
  'menu_position'    => 5,
   'supports'        => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt',     'comments' ),
    'taxonomies'         => array('category','post_tag'),
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
         'show_ui'           => true,
      'query_var'        => true,
     'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categories' ),
     'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
      'capability_type'    => 'post' );
       register_post_type( 'testimonial', $args );  
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
      }
      add_action( 'init', 'testimonial_postTypes' );

//sample


  function Doctor_post_types() {
        $labels = array(
         'name'               => _x( 'Doctor', 'doctor' ),
       'singular_name'      => _x( 'Doctor', 'doctor' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add Doctors', 'doctor' ),
       'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add Doctors' ),
       'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Doctors' ),
           'new_item'           => __( 'New Doctors' ),
          'all_items'          => __( 'All Doctors' ),
              'view_item'          => __( 'View Doctors' ),
             'search_items'       => __( 'Search Doctors' ),
           'not_found'          => __( 'No Doctors found' ),
              'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Doctors found in the Trash' ), 
              'parent_item_colon'  => '',
              'menu_name'          => 'Doctors',
            );
       $args = array(
            'labels'        => $labels,
               'description'   => 'Allows the user to create Doctor',
               'public'        => true,
                 'menu_position' => 5,
              'supports'   => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
               'has_archive'   => true,
               'show_ui'           => true,
                   'show_admin_column' => true,
                  'query_var'         => true,
                  'hierarchical'    => false,
                  '_builtin'     => false,
                  'capability_type' => 'post',
                  'rewrite'     => array('slug' => 'Doctor','with_front' => FALSE)

                   //'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
                   );
                   register_post_type( 'doctor', $args ); 
                    }
                   add_action( 'init', 'Doctor_post_types' );

                   function Doctors_taxonomies_product() {
                   $labels = array(
                    'name'              => _x( 'Doctor Categories', 'Doctor Categories' ),
                    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Doctor Categories', 'Doctor Categories' ),
                     'search_items'      => __( 'Search Doctor Categories' ),
                     'all_items'         => __( 'All Doctor Categories' ),
                     'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Doctor Categories' ),
                       'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Doctor Categories' ),
                     'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Doctor Categories' ), 
                     'update_item'       => __( 'Update Doctor Categories' ),
                     'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Doctor Categories' ),
                       'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Doctor Categories' ),
                     'menu_name'         => __( 'Doctor Categories' ),
                     'rewrite'           => array( 'Doctor-Categories' => 'doc-type' ),
                         );

              register_taxonomy( 'Doctor-Categories', array('doctor'), array(
             'hierarchical' => true,
             'labels' => $labels,
              'show_ui' => true,
             'show_admin_column' => true,
             'query_var' => true,
              'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Doctor-Categories' ),
              )); 

          }
        add_action( 'init', 'Doctors_taxonomies_product', 0 );


          ?>
```

I have created a taxonomy "doctor". In that I have created some posts of the taxonomy "doctor".

I wanted to display all the posts of this taxonomy in the site and also insert into the database into a table as post_type = 'doctor'How can I do this ? I have written the code. But it is not working.

Can anybody help me with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php query_posts("cat=33&post_type=doctor&showposts=-1");
     while(have_posts()): the_post();

the_title(); 


endwhile; wp_reset_query();
?>
```

i have also updated posts from the category 33 where posts type doctor .